# How to add zeros before and after each element in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the list

```
{0.2, 0.5, 0.7}
```

my desired list is:

```
{0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.}
```

Can it be done in a smarter way especially for a list with a much larger number (say 1000) of elements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Upsample[{0.2, 0.5, 0.7}, 3, 2]
```

> {0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.}

(Thanks: corey979)

Comment: @corey979, right; OPI thought OP wanted `{0., 0.2, 0., 0.5, 0., 0.7, 0., 0.}`:) thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This should be fast:

```
addZeros[arr_] :=
 Module[{res = ConstantArray[0, 3 Length[arr]]},
  res[[2 ;; -2 ;; 3]] = arr;
  res
 ]
```

If you use floating point numbers instead of integers, use `0.` in `ConstantArray` instead of `0` for improved performance.

---

Here's a performance-focused version:

```
iAddZeros[arr_, z_] := 
 Module[{res = ConstantArray[z, 3 Length[arr]]}, 
  res[[2 ;; -2 ;; 3]] = arr;
  res
 ]

addZeros[arr_ /; Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Real]] := iAddZeros[arr, 0.]

addZeros[arr_ /; Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Complex]] := iAddZeros[arr, 0. + 0. I]

addZeros[arr_] := iAddZeros[arr, 0]
```

Benchmark:

```
With[{arr = RandomReal[1, 100000]},
 addZeros[arr]; // RepeatedTiming
 ]
(* {0.00024, Null} *)
```

Comment: Can your answer be generalized such that `addZeros[arr_,n_] ` returns `{0., 0.2,0.2,0.2, 0., 0., 0.5,0.5,0.5, 0., 0., 0.7,0.7,0.7, 0.}` for `n=3`? I am having a problem to do this using `Span`.

Comment: You can assign three times, each time with a `Span` shifted by one.  Not pretty, but if you only need 3, it'll work.

Answer (score 8):

```
list = {0.2, 0.5, 0.7};
Riffle[ConstantArray[0., 2 Length[list]], list, {2, -2, 3}]
```

> ```
> {0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.}
> ```

If the `list`-elements should be repeated `n` times then

```
n = 3;
With[{z = ConstantArray[0., Length[list]]},
 Flatten[{{z}, ConstantArray[list, n], {z}}, {3, 1, 2}]]
```

> ```
> {0., 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Another option might be

```
lst = {0.2,0.5,0.7};
Flatten[{0.,#,0.}&/@lst]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
Replace[{0.2, 0.5, 0.7}, x_ :>  Sequence[0, x, 0], 1]
```

> {0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.7, 0}

**Edit**

As [Alexy Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) pointed out in a comment (and thanks!), it is safer to use rule-delayed as x is then effectively locally scoped,

```
 x = 100; Replace[{0.2, 0.5, 2}, x_ :> Sequence[0, x, 0], 1];
```

> {0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 2, 0}

rather than (original answer):

```
x = 100; Replace[{0.2, 0.5, 2}, x_ ->  Sequence[0, x, 0], 1]
```

> {0, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0}

Comment: Or `Cases[{0.2, 0.5, 0.7}, x_ -> Sequence[0, x, 0], 1]`

Comment: It is safer to use scoped version: `Replace[{0.2, 0.5, 0.7}, x_ :> Sequence[0, x, 0], 1]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks!  I had naively assumed that x was scoped locally in both constructs.

Answer (score 4):

Given a list of 1000 elements, say,

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[1., 1000];
```

there are many ways to do what you ask for. Here is one using [`Riffle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html).

```
augmented = 
  {0., Sequence @@ Riffle[data, Unevaluated @ Sequence[0., 0.]], 0.};
```

which produces

```
Short[augmented, 3]
```

> `{0., 0.425905, 0., 0., 0.391023, 0., 0., <2986>>, 
>   0., 0., 0.185166,0., 0., 0.249098, 0.}`

Comment: The OP wants the first element also to be `0.`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: OP also inserts 2 zeros in-between, not one.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. Maybe I finally got it right this time?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a soluton based on `SparseArray`. It's not as fast as `Szabolcs`' approach, though, even if one removes `Normal`.

```
Normal@SparseArray[
 Transpose[3 Range[{Length[data]}] - 1] -> data, 
 {3 Length[data]},
 0.
];
```

Answer (score 3):

Two more ways to achieve the requested result:

```
BlockRandom[

 (* generate 1000 random number *)
 rands = RandomReal[{-1,1},1000];

 (* use PadLeft/Right *)
 res1 = Flatten[
   PadLeft[PadRight[{#}, 2], 3] & /@ rands] // RepeatedTiming // Short;

 (* use Riffle *)
 res2 = ReleaseHold[
   Prepend[Append[Riffle[rands, Hold[Sequence[0, 0]]], 0], 0]] // RepeatedTiming // Short;

 {res1, res2}, RandomSeeding->123654789]
```

(see [PadLeft](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft.html), [Riffle](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Riffle.html?q=Riffle))

On my machine the timings are more or less the same (with the second one probably a bit faster)

Answer (score 3):

My slow and naive solution that's also somewhat easy to read:

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomReal[1., 1000];    
Flatten[Table[Prepend[Append[Take[data,i],0.],0.],{i,Length[data]}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {0.2, 0.5, 0.7};

SequenceCases[list, {x_} :> Sequence @@ {0, x, 0}]

Cases[list, x_ :> Sequence @@ {0, x, 0}]

Sequence @@@   Transpose[{ConstantArray[0, Length@list], list,     ConstantArray[0, Length@list]}]

Sequence @@ ArrayPad[#, {1, 1}] & /@ List /@ list
```

---

> {0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.7, 0}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {0.2, 0.5, 0.7};

Thread[{0, list, 0}] // Flatten

list /. x_?NumberQ :> Splice[{0, x, 0}]

Flatten[Append[0] /@ Prepend[0] /@ List /@ list]
```

{0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.7, 0}

Answer (score 1):

Another method using `Insert`:

```
PositionsToInsert[list_] := Outer[List, Sequence @@@ MapAt[-#[[2 ;; -2]] &, 
Array[Range[Length@list + 1] &, 2], {2}]]
```

Using `PositionsToInsert` with Insert:

```
Insert[#, 0, PositionsToInsert[#]] &@list

(*{0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.7, 0}*)
```

An example with another list:

```
list2 = {a, b, c, d, e};
Insert[#, 0, PositionsToInsert[#]] &@list2 === Cases[list2, x_ :> Sequence @@ {0, x, 0}]

(*True*)
```