# How to create a list from a plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

This is motivated by this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163802/how-to-add-zeros-before-and-after-each-element-in-a-list/163882#163882).

Consider the list

```
list={0.2, 0.5, 0.7};
```

If I plot the data using `ListLinePlot` I get a curve like this

[image: Plot1]

If I now apply interpolation using

```
ListLinePlot[{0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2]
```

I get

[image: Plot2]

Now I wish to find the list which includes the interpolated values along with the zero values between `3` to `4` and `6` to `7` to generate Plot2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** A single list of points with negative y-values clipped to 0:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.}, 
    InterpolationOrder -> 2,  PlotRange -> {-.2, 1}];
clippedpoints =  Cases[llp,  Line[x_] :> 
  Transpose[{#, Clip[#2, {0, Infinity}]} & @@ Transpose[x]], Infinity]

Show[llp, ListPlot[clippedpoints, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.01]]], 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

> True

---

**Original answer:**

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange -> {0, All}]; 
points = Cases[llp, Line[x__] :> x, Infinity];

points // Short[#, 4] &
```

> {{{1.,0.},{1.0234,0.00634228},{1.04853,0.0131544},{1.07539,0.0204362},{1.10399,0.0281879},<<45>>,{2.92412,0.0156563},{2.96203,0.00766473},{3.,3.46945*10^-18},{3.,0.}},{{<<18>>,0.},<<52>>},{<<1>>}}

```
Show[llp, ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.01]]], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: The original plot doesn't have any negative value. The negative values in your plot should be truncated to `0` as they are in the original list.

Comment: @Majis, please see the update.

Comment: The plot is now truncated but the truncated points (zero values) are not shown.

Comment: @Majis, there are no zero values in your original plot (due to the default plot range in version 11 you get  a picture that does not show negative values). You can see that clearly if you remove the axes: `ListLinePlot[{0., 0.2, 0., 0., 0.5, 0., 0., 0.7, 0.}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, Axes->False]`

Comment: Yes, true. But I need the zero values as well.

Comment: @Majis, please see the update.